# Showing the value of cell X1 in Excel

Tags: excel

In column A, I have numbers from 1 to 120 in a random order. When the number in column A is for example 1, I want excel to show in column B the value of cell X1. When the number in column A is 2, column B should show the value that is in cell X2 etc.

So now I made an extra column saying `= "=""X"A1`
Then I paste the values into a new column, but they don't show the exact values of cell X1, only =X1. I need to activate the function line, press Enter and only than the exact value of X1 shows up. Does anybody know how to solve this? Since I have >300 rows in each spreadsheet, this is not a thing I want to do manually..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `INDIRECT()`. e.g. `=INDIRECT("X" & A1)` will take the value in cell `A1`, combine it with the letter `X`, producing `X1`, then return the value in cell `X1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know the existence of the indirect function, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the Indirect function.

```
=INDIRECT("X"&A1)
```

This will create a range reference to Column X and the number in A becomes the Row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

=INDIRECT("X"&A1)